# Ocultar div no mobile

Tags: css, layout-responsivo

gostaria de uma ajuda se possível para esconder uma div no mobile.

Tentei usar

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    Elemento oculto para mobile
</div>
<div class="visible-xs">
    Elemento visível para mobile e oculto nas demais resoluções
</div>
```

mas não funcionou.

Meu código é este, só quero esconder no mobile.
Alguém por gentileza pode me "*helpar*"?

```html
<div class="hidden-sm"><div style="float: left; width: 33%;"><img src="/wp-content/imagens/km.png" /> <strong>Km:</strong> 56.433</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 33%;"><img src="/wp-content/imagens/ano.png" /> <strong>Ano:</strong> 2016</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 33%;"><img src="/wp-content/imagens/carroceria.png" /> <strong>Carroceria:</strong> Hatch</div>
&nbsp;
<div style="float: left; width: 33%;"><img src="/wp-content/imagens/cambio.png" /> <strong>Câmbio:</strong> Manual</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 33%;"><img src="/wp-content/imagens/aceitatroca.png" /> <b>Aceita troca:</b> Sim</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 33%;"><img src="/wp-content/imagens/licenciado.png" /> <b>Licenciado:</b> Sim</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Com Bootstrap 4.0

Se estiver utilizando o framework [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) para gerenciar os seus grids, você tem acesso as classes de Display [Link documentação Display Boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/utilities/display/) que são:

- **d-sm-none** - para esconder um elemento se a tela for maior que 576px
- **d-none d-sm-block** - para esconder se a tela for menor que 576px

No seu caso utilize a **d-sm-none** para esconder no mobile:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
     href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="d-sm-none">Esconde em telas maiores que sm</div>
    <div class="d-none d-sm-block">Esconde em telas menores que sm</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Sem Boostrap

Se você quiser fazer com puro CSS, você pode usar o media query [Link documentação media query](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
 .hidden-xs{
  display:none;
 }

 .visible-xs {
  display:block;
 }
}
```

Com isso você consegue fazer essa tratativa, espero ter te ajudado!

Comment: Desculpe, mas não entendi bem. Meu código é apenas  aquele a cima, onde eu vou adicionar esse css? abro um <style> ?